# JavaScript: Injecting content into DOM vs. hiding/showing desired content

Tags: javascript, dom

If I need to show different content (e.g., short text, few images) in html based on a certain binary condition (true/false), which of the following is generally considered a better way?

1. Injecting content into DOM: For example, this could be passing a text string into a `<span>` element.
2. Hiding/Showing desired content: I would have two separate `<div>` blocks each of which holds some content I want to display depending on the binary condition. Only one of them is in display at any given time.

I didn't provide a specific example because I intend it to be a general question. Thanks for your advice in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general, objective answer to this question. Do what you think is best, the best answer will vary on a case by case basis (and there may be no "best" answer in some cases).

Note that even when elements are hidden, most browsers will issue requests for the images in the hidden content. That may or may not be an objective reason for making a decision one way or the other (e.g., inject them on demand if you don't want those images requested when not shown, or don't if you do so they're pre-cached and show up immediately when the content is shown).